# Percentage of Wasted File Space

Tags: file, filesystems

Lets say a system stores files in blocks of 16000 bytes.  Then calculating the wasted file space from the incomplete filling of the last block for a file of size 4,064,0000 bytes and 640,000 bytes..

Divide them by 16000 and I get NO wasted space...What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like homework (tag it as such if it is). I doubt the block-size is 16,000 but rather 16KiB or 16 * 1024 bytes -> 16384 bytes. If the modulus is zero then, well all the blocks are "packed perfectly" in some idealized filesystem. (The actual implementation may not actually have these characteristic though!) For very large files, the wasted space approaches zero. Now, what if there were 20k files at 1-3KiB each?

Comment: It's quite hard to understand what you are asking about. Most prominently, what file system are you talking about and what makes you think you are doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't understand why this is being closed as 'off topic' (and two off-topic votes don't even redirect to somewhere relevant!). This does cover a programming topic/issues, even if slightly obscure and even if the question is perhaps not currently worded the best.